# Centos 7 FTP Hidden Directory Issue

Tags: centos, permissions, directory, ftp, chmod

After setting up Centos 7 with a web server standard install and LAMP stack. I installed vsftpd. Everything works fine and configured it to accept passive to enable gui ftp programs. However, when attempting to brows the file structure using FileZilla, upon moving up one directory, the previous directory disappears.

[image: First Screenshot of FileZilla]

[image: Second Screenshot of FileZilla]

As you can see from the images, home contains the directory 'nick' however, when moving up one directory to home, 'nick' disappears.

I'm guessing this is a permissions issue?